# Integral of the product of two nonnegative functions

Tags: calculus, optimization

So I am having some difficulty trying to show the following;

> Suppose $\int_a^b \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y'^2}L(x,y,y') w^2 dx \ge 0$, $\forall w$ s.t. $w(a)=w(b)=0$, show this implies $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y'^2}L(x,y,y')$ is nonnegative for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any additional hypothesis about these functions? Seems like you could consider $A = \{L_{yy} < 0\}$ and prove its measure is null using $w$ as its indicator function.

Comment: no other assumptions are given @σ_clp